# Jasmine tests have inconsistent results across test runs, between Firefox/Chrome, and with inspector on/off

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, jasmine

I am having a hell of a time trying to get a test to pass in Jasmine. It's on a page that has 10 rows. There is a button that toggles show/hide rows 4-10. The functionality works fine 100% of the time when testing by hand. However, when I run the below Jasmine test (it can show 10 total rows), it fails sometimes on Firefox, and works most times on Chrome (though sometimes having Chrome inspector open changes the test behavior)

Here is the test:

```
describe('Show / Hide feature', function() {
   beforeEach(function(){
    loadFixtures('tools_generate__codes.html');
    GenerateCodes.bind();
    GenerateCodesFunctions.hideExtraRows();
    GenerateCodesFunctions.toggleShowHideMore();
  });

  it('defaults to showing 3 rows', function() {
    expect($('.filenames >tbody > tr:visible').length === 3).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('can show 10 total rows', function() {
    $('.show_more').click();
    expect($('.filenames >tbody > tr:visible').length === 10).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and the code:

```
GenerateCodesFunctions = {
  toggleShowHideMore: function() {
    $('.show_more').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($('.show_more').html() === 'Show More') {
        alert("WTF");
        GenerateCodesFunctions.showExtraRows();
      } else {
        GenerateCodesFunctions.hideExtraRows();
      }
    });
  },

  hideExtraRows: function() {
    for (var i = 4; i <= 10; i++) {
      $("#generate__codes_filename" + i).val('');
      $("#generate__codes_filename" + i + "_count").val('');
      $("#generate__codes_filename" + i + "_prefix").val('');
      $("#generate__codes_filename" + i).parent().parent().hide();
    }
    $('.show_more').html("Show More");
  },

  showExtraRows: function() {
    for (var i = 4; i <= 10; i++) {
      $("#generate__codes_filename" + i).parent().parent().show();
    }
    alert('showed extra rows');
    $('.show_more').html("Show Less");
  }
};
```

What seems to be happening is that the .show_more button is clicked 2-3 times (alert 'wtf' shows up multiple times). The $('.show_more').click code only occurs once in the test. On both, it looks like the first click doesn't change the text of the button to "Show Less". On Chrome, the 2nd click changes the text to "Show Less", whereas on Firefox it doesn't, which I think is causing the problem.

Why is the button being clicked multiple times, and why doesn't it change the text of the button. Also, why is this behavior different on Firefox and on Chrome?

Comment: the solution to this is to not use jasmine

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was causing the problem. I stupidly just copied straight html from my page into the fixture, which was probably causing load fixtures to reload all the javascript files. I think either the reloading of the .js files was causing errors, or that the fact that the loading was slowed cause errors with the click event handling not always finished before the expectation (setting a timeout on the expectation caused the test to pass).